# Display images in twig using asset in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, twig

i have a list of objects which has an image as an attribute(name of the image as a string) , i am looping this list in twig and i try to display the image in an img html tag which takes it's source of image through a symfony 'asset' path . 
this the twig part of code :

```
{% for  offre in listeoffres  %}
    <li>   
        <img src="{{asset('images/')}} {{ offre.nomImage }}" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ offre.titre }}  
    </li>  
{% endfor %}
```

Notes :

- The database contains correct image names and the images already
  exist in the correct folder (`web/images`)
- The '{{ offre.nomImage }}' displays correctly the image name that
  it's in the database (with the extension)
- When i display  `{{asset('images/')}} {{ offre.nomImage }}` it shows:
  `/myproject/web/images/ image.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

While your solution works, Tthe correct way to use the `asset` function would be to pass the full path of the image to the function call:

```
{{ asset('images/' ~ offre.nomImage) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. The problem was the space between the asset and the image name.
So the image source should have been like this :

```
{{asset('images/')}}{{ offre.nomImage}}
```